# Problems using the Razor model when creating my knockout ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, razor-2

I'm having problems with using the Model in a javascript call when setting up my knockout VM..

```
@model List<AdminGui.Models.Domain>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.domains = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(@Model, function(item) {
            return new Domain(item.guid, item.description, item.namespaces);
        }));
}
```

I get a syntax error on @Model in the ko.utils.arrayMap call. I suspect it might be my Razor-fu that is lacking... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Model` is your C# model which cannot be used directly from JavaScript, because writing `@Model` just calls `ToString` on it which is not what you need.

What you need is to convert your Model to JSON, you can do this with the `Json.Encode` method

```
self.domains = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)), function(item) {
            return new Domain(item.guid, item.description, item.namespaces);
        }));
```

Note: You need to wrap it with `Html.Raw` to turn off the automatic HTML Encoding in Razor.

Comment: I strongly advice against inline Javascript or using Razor engine to render JSON inline. For a better, more maintainable and testable solution move the view model to a js-file with the same name as the model it contains (One file per model), use MVC4 bundling to reference the scripts on the page. Then use ASP.NET WebApi to get JSON data from the server